# Android: number of "new users" vs "daily installs by device"

Tags: android, statistics, installation, uninstallation

For my apps the number of "daily new users" in Google Analytics is always about 20% higher as "daily installs by device" displayed in the Developer Console.

What's the difference between "new users" and "daily installs"?

I heard that installs only count in Developer Console, if the user didn't uninstall the downloaded app within 3 days. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the install count in developer console has a 3-day delay.

According to [support document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en), "Daily installs by device" means devices which installed the app for the first time in the past day (which I guess is counted in PST timezone). In my own experience, the daily install count almost precisely matches the actual install count in a specific day.

"Daily New users" in Google Analytics means users that "first open" your app in the past day, so some of them may have installed the app on earlier date.

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [Google Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?hl=en)

> **Daily installs by device**: Devices which installed the app **for the
>   first time** in the past day
>
> **Daily installs by user**: Unique users who installed the app on **one or more of their devices** for the first time in the past day

My guessing is that it's possible to have more users than devices, specially if a device holds multiple users, right?

I hope that helps! Cheers

Comment: Actually that's reversed. More devices than users. It says, one or more of their devices. So Daily installs by user < Daily installs by device. As some users install your app on more devices (they have a tablet, a phone, etc.).